# How do I delete a data that contains spaces in Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have managed to delete a data in the firebase data base using this code, but it won't delete any data that contains spaces for example I tried to delete a data that is called "Test" it was deleted, but I have a data called "Test 1" but it won't get deleted, also some of the other data won't get deleted.

```
DeleteData1.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{

var deleteCrop1 = document.getElementById('deleteCrop').value;

  remove(ref(database, 'Crops/' + document.getElementById('deleteCrop').value))
  .then(()=>{
     alert("Crop successfully deleted");
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
     alert("Unsuccessful, error" + error);
  })
});
```

Comment: Upon checking, the only thing I can delete was the last entry added into the database. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/z9bkg6/how_do_i_delete_a_data_that_contains_spaces_in/